# how the output of the drupal hooks

Tags: drupal, hook

the drupal is 6.
1, in drupal.everything's output is by a theme function or a template file.is this right. if right,then question 2.

2,in a module there is a hook_link and hook_menu, how they output? i can't find a theme function or a template file effect it. thank you.

eg:in  book's module there is a book_link（） defined. but i can't find there is a heme_book_link()，and in hook_theme there is no return of the book_link.

Comment: A few minutes research hook_link(), hook_menu(), or any other at api.drupal.org would quickly reveal what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things that make understanding Drupal hooks:

1. They are just regular php functions.
2. Many times they don't return anything.
3. They are "called" by [module_invoke_all()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/6) or [module_invoke()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_invoke/6)

For Example: If module **foo** has a **hook_dosomething()** there is a function in foo.module that implements **module_invoke_all('foo', 'dosomething')**

The other way to think about it is that the hook "exteneds" a function someplace else, and anything that happens in the hook happens in the function that calls module_invoke_all() in it.

Comment: This is wrong. Many hooks DO RETURN IMPORTANT VALUES. Look no further than hook_menu to see why that blanket statement is incorrect.

Comment: Edited in response to Tyler's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Not all hooks generate output. hook_menu() and hook_link(), for example, just return arrays with data that will be used by Drupal in some way (e.g. to register new paths in the system).